# Add a constant to an existing column

Tags: python, python-polars

Dataframe:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "nrs": [1, 2, 3, None, 5],
        "names": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg", None],
        "random": rng.random(5),
        "A": [True, True, False, False, False],
    }
)
```

Currently, to add a constant to a column I do:

```
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('random') + 500.0)
```

Questions:

1. Why does `df = df.with_columns(pl.col('random') += 500.0)` throw a `SyntaxError`?
2. Various AIs tell me that `df['random'] = df['random'] + 500` should also work, but it throws the following error instead:

   ```
   TypeError: DataFrame object does not support `Series` assignment by index

   Use `DataFrame.with_columns`.
   ```

   Why is `polars` throwing an error? I've been using `df['random']` to identify the `random` column in other parts of my code, and it worked.

Comment: 1. Because you're trying to use an [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) as an expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### AI:s tell you to do so, because they are not actually intelligent

They try to suggest you how it's done in `pandas`, because of similar keywords like `dataframe` and `python`. But it just does not work the same way with `polars` by design.

### Augmented assignment problem

With `+=` too, it's really just a matter of syntax. `pl.col` is a class (of type `<class 'polars.functions.col.ColumnFactory'>`), and instantiating that class creates an expression (`<Expr ['col("random")'] at 0x701D91A7D850>`), but you cannot assign to that the same way as you cannot assign like this before `a` exists:

```
a += 1
```

Or more precisely, because you cannot do the same within any function call:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> math.pow(a += 10, 2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    math.pow(a += 10, 2)
               ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> math.pow(a + 10, 2)
400.0
```

Interestingly, you *can* do this:

```
>>> expr = pl.col("random")
>>> expr += 500
>>> expr
<Expr ['[(col("random")) + (500)]'] at 0x701D91AE4800>
>>> df.select(expr)
shape: (5, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ random     │
│ ---        │
│ f64        │
╞════════════╡
│ 500.773956 │
│ 500.438878 │
│ 500.858598 │
│ 500.697368 │
│ 500.094177 │
└────────────┘
```

So this works

```
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('random') + 500.0)
```

because it's basically equivalent to the previous example, you just create the expression on the same line as you do the `with_columns`.

Comment: Really good answer. I think the first sentence deserves to be in bold or as a heading (at least the initial clause before the comma..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just to be sure, can you confirm that `df = df.with_columns(pl.col('random') + 500.0)` is the "polaric" way to add a constant float to a column of float? If not, what's the best way? Seems a tad verbose, but I think this is the way `polars` is meant to be used.

Comment: A tad verbose yes, but the correct way. There's probably a good reason why it is like this, but I'm not too familiar with the internals. Other option is to use `.select(pl.col("random") + 500)` if you need it only temporarily. The documentation says that: "The main difference between with_columns and select is that with_columns retains the original columns and adds new ones, whereas select drops the original columns."